# Using JQuery and CSS to make an image gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been up for quite awhile trying to figure this out. On this website http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/slide1/ this gives me the code and everything and I have plugged it into my webpage just like it should be.

I updated it now this is my code can someone please help me with it...

```
     <html>
    <head>

    <style type="text/css">
    #slide1_controls span {
        padding-right:2em;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    #slide1_container {
        width:450px;
        height:281px;
        overflow:hidden;
        position:relative;
    }
    #slide1_images {
        position:absolute;
        left:0px;
        width:1800px;
        -webkit-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;    
        transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
    }
    #slide1_images img {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        float:left;
    }
    </style>

<script type="text/javscript" 

src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#slide1-1").click(function() {
            $("#slide1_images").css("left","0");
        });
        $("#slide1-2").click(function() {
            $("#slide1_images").css("left","-450px");
        });
        $("#slide1-3").click(function() {
            $("#slide1_images").css("left","-900px");
        });
        $("#slide1-4").click(function() {
            $("#slide1_images").css("left","-1350px");
        });
    });

    </script>


    </head>
    <body>


    <div id="slide1_container">
        <div id="slide1_images">
            <img src="pictures/1.jpg" />
            <img src="pictures/2.jpg" />
            <img src="pictures/3.jpg" />
            <img src="pictures/4.jpg" />        
        </div>
    </div>
    <p id="slide1_controls">
        <span id="slide1-1">Image 1</span>
        <span id="slide1-2">Image 2</span>
        <span id="slide1-3">Image 3</span>
        <span id="slide1-4">Image 4</span>
    </p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

But no matter what I do I cannot get this to work and I really need it for my current website.

Comment: can you show your complete markup?

Comment: make sure if you are including the jquery library file

Comment: spencer check my answer. You've just placed the script and style tags in the wrong area in your html page. both those tags are always placed within the head tags.

Comment: The complete markup would be to large for me to put on here, I guess what Im asking is how would I plugin the jquery correctly Ive never used it before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

include jquery file in your code.

[tutorial](https://www.google.co.in/search?rlz=1C1CHMD_enIN473IN473&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=how%20to%20include%20link%20of%20jquery%20in%20html)

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#slide1-1").click(function() {
            $("#slide1_images").css("left","0");
        });
        $("#slide1-2").click(function() {
            $("#slide1_images").css("left","-450px");
        });
        $("#slide1-3").click(function() {
            $("#slide1_images").css("left","-900px");
        });
        $("#slide1-4").click(function() {
            $("#slide1_images").css("left","-1350px");
        });
    });
    </script>
    <div id="slide1_container">
        <div id="slide1_images">
            <img src="/images/Cirques.jpg" />
            <img src="/images/Clown%20Fish.jpg" />
            <img src="/images/Stones.jpg" />
            <img src="/images/Summit.jpg" />        
        </div>
    </div>
    <p id="slide1_controls">
        <span id="slide1-1">Image 1</span>
        <span id="slide1-2">Image 2</span>
        <span id="slide1-3">Image 3</span>
        <span id="slide1-4">Image 4</span>
    </p>
```

Comment: This more or less solved it, it gave me an idea on what was wrong thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you have not included jQuery file then you have to include also that to run this jQuery code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#slide1-1").click(function() {
    $("#slide1_images").css("left","0");
});
$("#slide1-2").click(function() {
    $("#slide1_images").css("left","-450px");
});
$("#slide1-3").click(function() {
    $("#slide1_images").css("left","-900px");
});
$("#slide1-4").click(function() {
    $("#slide1_images").css("left","-1350px");
});
```

});